# Make the auosizing TextView size be same

Tags: android, textview, autosize

I used autoSizing TextView in RecyclerView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_id"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="12sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_price"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="12sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

The font size are different , because of the content

[image]

I log the size

```
 Log.e("price", holder.getAdapterPosition() + "--" + price.getTextSize());
```

this is the result

```
2018-12-06 18:10:24.394 31179-31179/com.sskj.moudle E/price: 0--42.0
2018-12-06 18:10:24.447 31179-31179/com.sskj.moudle E/price: 1--42.0
2018-12-06 18:10:24.480 31179-31179/com.sskj.moudle E/price: 2--42.0
2018-12-06 18:10:24.515 31179-31179/com.sskj.moudle E/price: 3--42.0
2018-12-06 18:10:24.555 31179-31179/com.sskj.moudle E/price: 4--42.0
```

As you see the sizes are different,I want to know how to make these sizes be same? 
                                                             Thank you!

Comment: if you don't want this behaviour then why use it. remove autosize and set text to fixed size.

Comment: Did u get the solution for this

Comment: @karan Can you please suggest how to set the highest textview size for all items irrespective of text sizes as we can see textview size decreases with increase in text size and vice versa. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView` each item are independent of each other, So second item may not know the size of the first item in `RecyclerView`.

One way to handle this scenario is to set maximum length `(android:maxLength=SIZE)` of `TextView` pad the text with empty spaces for smaller text and show ellipses for longer text.